# How to drag and drop element into new div using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to follow the guide [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) to make drag and drop work for my site, but I'm running across a problem catching the `drop` event.

Pretty much what I want to do is allow users to drag an element into the div at the bottom, and once they actually drop it in, it will add it to that div.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FwWR/1/). As you can see, the `handleDrop` function I created never gets called.

I've also tried to add the eventListener "drop" on the individual elements instead of the one that they will be dropped into, but that doesn't seem to work either. I've commented this out in the fiddle. Any help?

Comment: Check out the [jQuery UI Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/twctZ/), and another approach.

**HTML**

```
<img id="1" src="/" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Image 1"/>
<img id="2" src="/" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Image 2"/>
<img id="3" src="/" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Image 3"/>
<img id="4" src="/" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Image 4"/>
<img id="5" src="/" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="Image 5"/>

<div id="playlist" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#playlist {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0;
  width: 960px;
  min-height:160px;
  background-color:#e5e5e5;
}
#playlist img {
  margin: 5px;
}
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

**JS**

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I want. How can you make it so it adds a copy to the `playlist` div instead of actually moving it?